# Orthogonal Complement of Direct Sum

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, direct-sum

I'm having some trouble with finding the orthogonal complement of a direct sum. To be precise, consider the Hilbert Space $\mathcal{H}$ of mean-zero random functions with finite variance, where the $\mathcal{H}$ is equipped with the covariance inner product.

Is it true that for any sets $A, B$:

$$(A \oplus B)^{\perp} = (A^{\perp} \oplus B^{\perp})?$$

i.e. the orthogonal complement of a direct sum is the direct sum of complements?

To put things into context, I was trying to figure out lemma 20 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.08526.pdf) and I don't understand why that proof is complete.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: $\oplus$ refers to the direct sum.

Comment: Actually it's easy to see from the definition that if $A$ and $B$ are subspaces of a Hilbert space then $(A+ B)^\perp=A^\perp\cap B^\perp$. (If, as in your question, $A$ and $B$ are just sub_sets_ then I have no idea what $A\oplus B$ is supposed to  mean...)

Comment: Sorry I should have been more precise. $\oplus$ refers to the direct sum (i.e. $A \oplus B = \{ a(X) + b(X) : a(X) \in A, b(X) \in B \}$, where $a(X)$ is a one-dimensional function of $X \in \mathbb{R}^d$). I don't think I'm looking for $A^{\perp} \cap B^{\perp}$...

Comment: The definition you give for $A\oplus B$ makes no sense to me. It's curious that you say you're not looking for $A^\perp\cap B^\perp$; if $A$ and $B$ are subspaces (with trivial intersection) then $(A\oplus B)^\perp$ _is_ $A^\perp\cap B^\perp$, regardless of whether that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Why I say your definition makes no sense: First,  I have no idea what a "one-dimension function of $X\in\Bbb R^d$ might be. But whatever that means, if $a(X)$ is one of those then $a(X)\notin H$.

Comment: I think I see why I got confused now... In the book (Semiparametric Theory and Missing Data) I'm reading, $W = M \oplus N$ if (1) $W = M + N$ and (2) $w \in W$ can be uniquely represented as $w = m + n$ for some $m \in M$ and some $n \in N$. I wasn't aware that the two subspaces must have trivial intersection.

Comment: I mentioned that "I'm not looking for $A^{\perp} \cap B^{\perp}$" because the lemma in the paper (which I'm trying to understand) didn't have any intersections in their result. So I was under the impression that $(A \oplus B)^{\perp} = (A^{\perp} \oplus B^{\perp})$ (which is not true now that you have explained things). This leaves me a little perplexed about the lemma described in the paper though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we should note that the direct sum $A\oplus B$ is defined only for *subspaces* $A$ and $B$ (and not for just any two subsets!). If $A$ and $B$ are just subsets of $H$, we can define the *sum* $$A+B=\{a+b:a\in A, b\in B\},$$and now **if** $A$ and $B$ are subspaces and **if** $A\cap B=\{0\}$ **then** the sum is said to be the "direct sum" of $A$ and $B$: $$A\oplus B=A+B.$$

And for $A\subset H$ we define $$A^\perp=\{x\in H: <x,a>=0\,\forall a\in A\},$$and note that $A^\perp=S^\perp$ if $S$ is the span of $A$ (or the closed span). At least if $A$ and $B$ both contain the origin, determining $(A+B)^\perp$ is trivial:

> > **Trivial Exercise.** If $A,B\subset H$ and $0\in A\cap B$ then $(A+B)^\perp=A^\perp\cap B^\perp$.

(Hence $(A\oplus B)^\perp=A^\perp\cap B^\perp$ in the only case in which $A\oplus B$ is defined, namely $A$ and $B$ are subspaces with trivial intersection.)

We give the proof, since the OP has expressed some skepticism: First, $0\in B$ shows that $A\subset A+B$, hence $(A+B)^\perp\subset A^\perp$. Similarly $(A+B)^\perp\subset B^\perp$, so $(A+B)^\perp\subset A^\perp\cap B^\perp$.

The other inclusion is even easier. Suppose $x\in A^\perp\cap B^\perp$. Then $$<x,a+b>=<x,a>+<x,b>=0+0=0\quad(a\in A,  b\in B),$$so $x\in(A+B)^\perp$.